# Questions with Windows More command

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, tail

I have to read log files on windows server and display it to the users.
I don't have to display all the info. from the file.
In unix, I can do tail -100, to get the latest 100 lines and with some research, I can grep  or  get the information after that text.
But, in windows, I'm using 'more' which is not working out for me.

The ones I tried so far, and reading the whole file.

```
    more <filename.txt>OutPutFile.txt
```

I want to do one of the below:

1. I need to read latest 'x' number of lines.
2. Read the log file, after a specific date. So, that I can get all the lines of logs, starting with a specific date.
   For instance, I can have all the log info. after  from the file.
3. Even working with PowerShell commands are also fine, but cannot install any 3rd party apps on my servers.

Please help me with my problem. thanks.

Comment: It's uncclear what you are asking. There are GnuWin ports of tail if you want that. Otherwise I'd recommend to switch to PowerShells Select-String with -context parameter.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to `[Find|FindStr] /N` the first line number containing your date, then use `More +n` where `n` is relative to that line number. I'm sure that you will find examples of both commands in use so that you can create your own code and update your question accordingly; Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete batch file example based on the comment I made:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=: %%A In ('FindStr/NL "08/19/2017" "in.log"'
) Do @If Not Defined i (Set/A "i=%%A-1"&Call More +%%i%% "in.log">"out.log")
```

*Change the names of the "in.log" and "out.log" files and date between the double quotes, `08/19/2017`, to match your known names, dates and formats.*

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for a remote connection and run the batch file.
Was able tot retrieve the information required. Will check with the client, if that is satisfactory or supposed to be only for that day, as this can be used many days after running the flow.